# MK_E_UNAVAILABLE in Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")

Tags: c#

0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE) error occurs in my case when UAC (User Account Control) isn't set to the un-restrictive "Never Notify Me".

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wd = 
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");`

The error is thrown when the code is run after publishing and installing the project. While debugging in the editor instead, everything is fine.

Is this due to security settings or credentials ? How to write such code correctly pls ?

Win Word is open and a document is open too, of course, and this code has always worked fine with UAC set to "Never Notify Me".

Comment: Explaining this with a UAC notification setting change is a stretch.  The error code simply means that it cannot find a running instance of Word.  Which is easily explained by Word not running.  Add details to your question: how did you make sure that Word is in fact running?

Comment: Thank you. Actually I did not intend to explain, but to just report an observation. I found the connection to UAC by coincidence. My code has always worked fine, and it does so again with UAC set to the least restrictive level. Word just IS running, and if not, the code is intended to be silent on this point, and indeed it is. With UAC set restrictively the code continues to find word and is errorless as long as run in debug mode (in the editor).

Answer (score 1):

Running word as a service is nasty business see for instance [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757?wa=wsignin1.0) . I went through quite a few problems making it work. The way I made it work was to run it in separate process which launches it only once. The main program communicates with the process by sending commands as strings to stdin of the process and waiting for response on the stdout. If the response does not come in time allotted the process is killed and restarted

Comment: thank you, @M.Feingold, pls note that I've modified my question + hope enough in tune with the rules. Hasn't it become a much more interesting question now? Best